# How to route the user and keep the paramater in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue with nodejs. I route the user from www.example.com/en-US to www.example.com but I want to keep the en-US in the redirected link, when I tried to add it it said as an error en-US subdirectorie doesn't exist.
Here is my code, couls any one help?

```
var i18n = require("i18n");

i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr-FR'],
    defaultLocale: 'fr-FR',
    directory: __dirname + '/locales',
    cookiename: 'locale'
});

app.get('/:locales/about', function(req, res) {
    var language = req.params.language;
     res.cookie('locale', language); 
    i18n.setLocale(language);
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a param naming issue.

try this

```
app.get('/:language/about', function(req, res) {  //change locales to language
    var language = req.params.language;
     res.cookie('locale', language); 
    i18n.setLocale(language);
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

mimic WordPress's custom URL structure which relies on .htaccess MOD_REWRITE to accomplish it.